# MS SQL service won't start after power outage (3 Updates)

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, service

There was a brief power outage a few days ago where i live, and when i rebooted my Windows 7 computer with MS SQL 2008 R2 on it, everything seems to be working fine, except the MS SQL service wont start.  I'm pretty sure no one was even using the database when the power went out.

When using SQL Server Configuration Manager to try and start the service again it says:

```
The request failed, or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
Consult the log or other applicable error logs for details.
```

When running sqlsrvr.exe, it says that it is resorting my database, and then it says it is done restoring it, but it just sits there and does nothing for hours, and the service never gets started.

Please Help!

**Update:**
So when starting it through the configuration monitor, nothing gets put in the error log, but when running the sqlservr.exe, this is what it outputs, then just sits there doing nothing:

```
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )

2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      All rights reserved.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      Server process ID is 2468.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.', System Model: 'EP43-UD3L'.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3716 at 11/6/2010 4:19:02 PM (local) 11/6/2010 11:19:02 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.83 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
    -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
    -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
    -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2010-11-07 16:06:32.84 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.84 Server      Detected 4 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.94 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.95 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:32.98 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.07 spid7s      1 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.08 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.08 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.17 spid7s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.17 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.17 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.18 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'MSSQLSERVER'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.21 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2010-11-07 16:06:33.21 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.22 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.50.1600. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.35 spid11s     Starting up database 'model'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.35 spid7s      Server name is 'XXXXXXX'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.42 spid11s     Clearing tempdb database.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.48 spid13s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid14s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid15s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid13s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid16s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid17s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.49 spid19s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.50 spid18s     Starting up database 'XXXXXXX'.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.51 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.51 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.51 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.52 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x54b, state: 3. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.
2010-11-07 16:06:33.58 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:34.28 spid15s     1 transactions rolled forward in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:34.56 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:34.56 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-11-07 16:06:35.26 spid11s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2010-11-07 16:06:35.59 spid13s     The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2010-11-07 16:06:35.59 spid13s     The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2010-11-07 16:06:35.64 spid13s     Service Broker manager has started.
2010-11-07 16:06:38.52 spid7s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Here is the only warning that i recieve when the computer boots up.  The source of it is User Profile Services (as per the Event Viewer):

```
    Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.  

 DETAIL - 
 6 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000:
Process 616 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000
Process 616 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000
Process 980 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000\Printers\DevModePerUser
Process 616 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed
Process 616 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
Process 616 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1327984882-2424197892-1977549990-1000\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA
```

After this, the next event log says that the User Profile Service has stopped (Information log).

**Update 2:**
I tried restoring to a restore point from before the power outage, but that didn't help anything. Also, when running sqlservr.exe it turns out that the sql server actually is working when i run that, i just never bothered to check. So as long as that command window stays open, the sql server is accessible, but i would like to get the service working again.  Do you guys suggest backing up my database and reinstalling SQL server?

**Update 3:**
Here are the system event errors when trying to start the service:

```
Error1:
The MSSQLSERVER service was unable to log on as .\Username with the currently configured password due to the following error: 
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
To ensure that the service is configured properly, use the Services snap-in in Microsoft Management Console (MMC).

Error 2:
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the Windows event logs?
There are likely to be useful clues in the system or application logs around the time you attempt to start the services (and during boot, though there they will be mixed with a pile of messages from other services and startup steps)

Comment: All of the SQL related ones are Information logs, and are exactly the same as what i posted from the log file.  There are no errors during boot up, but one warning. I've posted it as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be having a disk problem? Are you writing your logs or indexes to another volume that may be full? Or maybe there's not enough free space on the db volume to do the recovery?

Comment: Hmm, i have 25 GB free on my C drive (where i assume the db is stored), and all my other drives have more than that. Also, in my 2nd update i mentioned that the server does work when running sqlservr.exe, just the service is the thing that fails to start.

Comment: How big Is the db? If the db is > 25gig then it might be running out of space trying to create the new one. Maybe this is a small database but if it's not usually folks store the data files on another volume that's not the boot disk.

Comment: No, its pretty small. Like < 1GB.

Comment: I assume that your system event log shows only informational messages?  I know you already answered one event log question, just want to be certain that the system event log has been examined.

Comment: jl, you might be on to something. In the event viewer for system logs, there are 2 error messages when trying to start the sql service. I'll add it to my post, since the formatting is coming out weird here in the commnet.

Comment: jl, I manually reentered my password into each of the services, and it seems to work now. If you want to create a separate answer i will accept it, as you were the one who came the closest to solving it.